# Can I use an AndroidX-compatible library with a non-AndroidX-compatible application?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, androidx

I am an author of a Java library for Android.

I would like to stop using Android Support Library in my library and change it to AndroidX.

In other words, I will add the following to my library's `gradle.properties`.

```java
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

If I set this, the Android Support Library should be disabled.

However, when I embedded my library into an app that "uses" the Android Support Library (i.e., an app with `android.useAndroidX=false`), the app was able to use the Support Library features.

Why is this?

Even if AndroidX is enabled in an external library, can apps that incorporate that library continue to use the support libraries?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is completely the contrary. Those lines are used IN the app's `gradle.properties` to: first, make use of AndroidX libraries instead of the Android Support Library; and second, to translate third party libraries (in this case yours) to make them use AndroidX instead.

Having said this, an app with those lines can use AndroidX by default and the current version of your library to transform it to AndroidX.

If you migrate your library to AndroidX then any app with `android.useAndroidX=false` won't be able to use that new version. It breaks backwards compatibility.

In case you want to keep giving compatibility to non AndroidX apps you should maintain two branches: One without AndroidX, probably just receiving hotfixes and the other with androidX that also receives fixes and features.

In case of the contrary it is worth it to mention at least the breaking version in case someone wants to use it on its non AndroidX app

Comment: As a matter of fact, it is possible to incorporate my library built with useAndroidX=true into an app with useAndroidX=false set.
For example, android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity and android.support.v4.content.FileProvider worked. Why is this?

Comment: I suppose you mean you only changed those flags and you didn't migrate yet, then the reason is because these flags are not exported to apps. They are Gradle properties, and thus they are only used during building/assemble time. An app HAS to set them up also on its side.

Comment: In case of the contrary, and you also migrated to AndroidX, then you could have defined the AndroidX dependencies as "api" instead of "implementation", is it?

In that case your app is propagating up the androidX dependencies transitively to the app which would have both AndroidX and Android Support Library at the same time, using the appropriate in every case.